# Bootstrap check-boxes are not on the same line with the text?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to create the check-boxes that will work with AngularJS. And also I need to style it in columns, 2 check-boxes in a column.

Here is what I did so far:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        Check All
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll.value" ng-click="checkAll()" />
    </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="carType in carTypeObj">
    <label>
        {{carType.type}}
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="carType.selected" />
    </label>
</div>
```

AngularJS code isn't needed in this question.
I all my CSS is connected to classes.

So I am using bootstrap 3.2 and I use `checkbox` class in my check-box `div`. Here is my output:

[image]

And here is my expected output:

[image]

**How can I achieve my goal?**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eap2hkkg/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eap2hkkg/1/)

Try this code:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll.value" ng-click="checkAll()" />Check All
</label>
```

Comment: But how can I style my check-boxes in columns, 2 check-boxes in a column?

Comment: @MichaelVayvala i didn't understand what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll.value" ng-click="checkAll()" />
        Check All
    </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="carType in carTypeObj">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="carType.selected" />
        {{carType.type}}
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and Maddy`s?

Comment: Maybe none I think that having the entire code makes more sense.